# Git submodules removing on checkout another branch

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have several branches with features in my Git repo.
Every feature is some foreign repo, plugged in as a submodule.
What should I do to correct switching between branches, with and without submodules?

**Example:**

```
$ git init
$ git commit -m "empty" --allow-empty
$ git checkout -b feature
$ git submodule init
$ git submodule add git://feature.git feature
$ git commit -a -m "add feature"
$ git checkout master
warning: unable to rmdir feature: Directory is not empty
```

And we have a feature in our `master` branch work directory.
How to prevent this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
git submodule deinit .
```

may do the trick

Comment: This works well. After I finished working with the branch, I came back and then did a `git submodule init` which registered the submodule back.

Answer (score 6):

With Git 2.27 (Q2 2020), the situation should improve, and "`git checkout --recurse-submodules`" works better with a nested submodule hierarchy.

See [commit 846f34d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/846f34d3514b81764dea7c2a4851f6187ab31aad), [commit e84704f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e84704f15ca793a377cb6ef24ab614b95775d008), [commit 16f2b6b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/16f2b6bb365c19e2424c58428af20dbe04af09c9), [commit 8d48dd1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8d48dd1988e90c7bfa966eb324ed98849528502a), [commit d5779b6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d5779b61d83e099a7c9249010dbd1aa1417efba0), [commit bd35645](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bd35645be21fdb0810b7dc01d680ef7bdfa07649) (17 Feb 2020) by [Philippe Blain (`phil-blain`)](https://github.com/phil-blain).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit fe87060](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fe870600fe2735782e9e8a8c5441f91b1a58e273), 27 Mar 2020)</sup>

> ### [`unpack-trees`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e84704f15ca793a377cb6ef24ab614b95775d008): check for missing submodule directory in `merged_entry`
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Philippe Blain</sup>
>   <sup>Reported-by: Damien Robert</sup>
>   <sup>Signed-off-by: Philippe Blain</sup>
>
> Using `git checkout --recurse-submodules` to **switch between a branch with no submodules and a branch with initialized nested submodules** currently causes a fatal error:
>
> ```
> $ git checkout --recurse-submodules branch-with-nested-submodules
> fatal: exec '--super-prefix=submodule/nested/': cd to 'nested'
>        failed: No such file or directory
> error: Submodule 'nested' could not be updated.
> error: Submodule 'submodule/nested' cannot checkout new HEAD.
> error: Submodule 'submodule' could not be updated.
> M   submodule
> Switched to branch 'branch-with-nested-submodules'
> ```
>
> The checkout succeeds, but the worktree and index of the first level submodule are **left empty**:
>
> ```
> $ cd submodule
> $ git -c status.submoduleSummary=1 status
> HEAD detached at b3ce885
> Changes to be committed:
>   (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
>       deleted:    .gitmodules
>       deleted:    first.t
>       deleted:    nested
>
> fatal: not a git repository: 'nested/.git'
> Submodule changes to be committed:
>
> * nested 1e96f59...0000000:
>
> $ git ls-files -s
> $ # empty
> $ ls -A
> .git
> ```
>
> **The reason for the fatal error during the checkout is that a child git process tries to `cd` into the yet unexisting nested submodule directory.**
>
> The sequence is the following:
>
> 1. The main git process (the one running in the superproject) eventually reaches `write_entry()` in [`entry.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e84704f15ca793a377cb6ef24ab614b95775d008/entry.c), which creates the first level submodule directory and then calls `submodule_move_head()` in [`submodule.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e84704f15ca793a377cb6ef24ab614b95775d008/submodule.c), which spawns `git read-tree` in the submodule directory.
> 2. The first child git process (the one in the submodule of the superproject) eventually calls `check_submodule_move_head()` at `unpack_trees.c:2021`, which calls `submodule_move_head` in dry-run mode, which spawns `git read-tree` in the nested submodule directory.
> 3. The second child git process tries to `chdir()` in the yet unexisting nested submodule directory in `start_command()` at [`run-command.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e84704f15ca793a377cb6ef24ab614b95775d008/run-command.c) and dies before exec'ing.
>
> The reason why `check_submodule_move_head()` is reached in the first child and not in the main process is that it is inside an `if(submodule_from_ce())` construct, and `submodule_from_ce()` returns a valid struct submodule pointer, whereas it returns a null pointer in the main git process.
>
> The reason why `submodule_from_ce()` returns a null pointer in the main `git` process is because the call to `cache_lookup_path()` in `config_from()` (called from `submodule_from_path()` in `submodule_from_ce()`) returns a null pointer since the hashmap `"for_path"` in the `submodule_cache` of `the_repository` is not yet populated.
>   It is not populated because both `repo_get_oid(repo, GITMODULES_INDEX, &oid)` and `repo_get_oid(repo, GITMODULES_HEAD, &oid)` in `config_from_gitmodules()` at [`submodule-config.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e84704f15ca793a377cb6ef24ab614b95775d008/submodule-config.c) return `-1`, as at this stage of the operation, neither the HEAD of the superproject nor its index contain any `.gitmodules` file.
>
> In contrast, in the first child the hashmap is populated because `repo_get_oid(repo, GITMODULES_HEAD, &oid)` returns 0 as the HEAD of the first level submodule, i.e. `.git/modules/submodule/HEAD`, points to a commit where `.gitmodules` is present and records 'nested' as a submodule.
>
> Fix this bug by checking that the submodule directory exists before calling `check_submodule_move_head()` in `merged_entry()` in the `if(!old)` branch, i.e. if going from a commit with no submodule to a commit with a submodule present.
>
> Also protect the other call to `check_submodule_move_head()` in `merged_entry()` the same way as it is safer, even though the `else if (!(old->ce_flags & CE_CONFLICTED))` branch of the code is not at play in the present bug.
>
> The other calls to `check_submodule_move_head()` in other functions in `unpack_trees.c` are all already protected by calls to `lstat()` somewhere in the program flow so we don't need additional protection for them.
>
> All commands in the `unpack_trees` machinery are affected, i.e. checkout, reset and read-tree when called with the `--recurse-submodules` flag.
>
> This bug was [first reported here](https://lore.kernel.org/git/7437BB59-4605-48EC-B05E-E2BDB2D9DABC@gmail.com/).

Answer (score 4):

It seems the easiest way is manually deleting the submodule directories. The price is you have to `git submodule init && git submodule update` after every checkout.

To match the directories from `.gitmodules`:

```
grep path .gitmodules | sed 's/.*= //'
```

*From [Prelang/gist/git-submodule-names](https://github.com/Prelang/g/blob/559493749dd7954897e26401368dc333e0401d70/bin/git-submodule-names)

To remove it:

```
grep path .gitmodules | sed 's/.*= //' | xargs rm -rf
```

Comment: Manually removing is weird, when we have a lot of different submodules in different branches. :(

Comment: Each branch has its own `.gitsubmodule` right? I would use a script to extract info from it and remove accordingly. It is after all a workaround till `git checkout` has the feature to handle submodules.

Comment: `.gitmodules`, right, or has not it at all. Yes, I can to do much things by shell scripts, but my question is "is any way to do it using `git` functionality?" Can you provide any working solution in your answer, may be some git hook with custom script?

Comment: With `git` only I do not know how. I am also not very familiar with shell script. But I have found something.