# Why is performance of lstat poor on APFS (OSX) compared to Ext4 (Linux)

Tags: git, stat, apfs

While profiling Git on a large repository, I found that git status is significantly (10x) slower on mac compared to linux. git status runs `lstat` on every file in the repository, which is where the slowness comes from.

Is there a particular reason why this syscall is much slower on macs compared to linux?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check first you version of Git, as there have been improvements in recent Git version (like [`git add` in 2.20](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53346723/6309), [git stash in 2.22](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59347116/6309) and even the [upcoming 2.27 with submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60905327/6309)).

Even [`git status` improved with Git 2.24](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43644347/6309)

> The `feature.manyFiles` setting is suitable for repos with many files in the working directory.
>   By setting `index.version=4` and `core.untrackedCache=true`, commands such as '`git status`' should improve.

---

One analysis of the difference of lstats in APFS compared to Ext4 was done in "[Global Kernel Locks in APFS](https://gregoryszorc.com/blog/2018/10/29/global-kernel-locks-in-apfs/)" by **[Gregory Szorc](https://github.com/indygreg)**:

> It is apparent that macOS 10.14 Mojave has received performance work relative to macOS 10.13!
>    Despite those improvements, APFS is still spending a lot of CPU time in the kernel. And the kernel CPU time is still comparatively very high compared to Linux/EXT4, even for single process operation.
>
> While the source code for APFS is not available for me to confirm, the profiling results showing excessive time spent in `lck_mtx_lock_grab_mutex()` combined with the fact that execution time decreases when the parallel process count decreases leads me to the conclusion that APFS obtains a global kernel lock during read-only operations such as readdir().
>
> In other words, APFS slows down when attempting to perform parallel read-only I/O.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and especially the quote + link by Gregory Szorc.

Based on your citation, it appears git is going to maintain the bottleneck on Mac relative to other systems regardless of underlying improvements in git itself, as those should also improve other systems. Yet another hidden cost to the Mac OS environment.