# What are the negative consequences of setting `feature.manyFiles` for small to mid-size repositories?

Tags: git

`git` provides a [`feature.manyFiles`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-featuremanyFiles) option that intends to make experiences in large repository smooth. What would be the consequences of turning it on also for small to mid-size repositories, such as:

```
git config --global feature.manyFiles true
```

Answer (score 7):

As of October 13 2023 one downside is that feature.manyFiles = true is not compatible with all git implementations. In particular, feature.manyFiles defaults index.skipHash to true and libgit2 is incompatible with index.skipHash = true. Many popular git GUI clients such as GitKraken use libgit2 making this a widespread issue.

https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/issues/6531

Answer (score 3):

I mentioned this option in [Git 2.24 (Q1 2019)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43644347/6309).
And, as [I noted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61264915/6309), that option would not change much on macOS.

That option was originally [discussed here](https://public-inbox.org/git/0d4774d45fee108981a4ad7316367f78c9f23fa1.1564515324.git.gitgitgadget@gmail.com/T/#m64d1a81d7cfd5bd8f8cfd40c3b061d5d9eea1c76), and [also here](https://public-inbox.org/git/1beedcb5ba112b05f6ef9cd306378b140ca73f8c.1673022717.git.gitgitgadget@gmail.com/T/#mc6e45d21f5dbbb32643accb0f98404baf4a24731); after this [2019 discussion](https://public-inbox.org/git/pull.254.git.gitgitgadget@gmail.com/).

> The `feature.manyFiles` setting is suitable for repos with many files in the working directory.
> By setting `index.version=4` and `core.untrackedCache=true`, commands such as '`git status`' should improve.

It should not impact small to medium repositories (since they are small-er, the optimization extra work won't be a big enough factor to be noticeable)
And it will improve `git status` for larger repositories.

But, as noted in [pholly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19961268/pholly)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77290211/6309) and in [`libgit2/libgit2` issue 6531](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/issues/6531), a downside has emerged where `feature.manyFiles = true` is not compatible with all Git implementations. Particularly, it defaults `index.skipHash` to true, which is incompatible with [libgit2](https://libgit2.org/).

By setting `index.skipHash` to true, that creates index files that libgit2 cannot handle. Consequently, operations in libgit2 fail with an error indicating invalid data in the index due to a mismatch in the calculated checksum​1​.